# jquery filter() return function confusion in my code

Tags: javascript, jquery

I expect the wrap that contain `img` and `video` tag will be excluded from applying the red background. I use has() but it doesn't seem working.

```js
$('document').ready(function(){

    
    var plainText = $('.wrap').not(':has(img, video)');

  $('.wrap').filter(function( index ) {
    return $(this).not(':has(img, video)');
  }).css( "background-color", "red" );
    
});
```

```css
.wrap{
    border: 1px solid;
    display: block;
    margin: 10px 0 10px 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrap">
    <div class="content">
        abc
    </div>
</div>


<div class="wrap">
    <div class="content">
        <img>
            
        </img>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="wrap">
    <div class="content">
        <video></video>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: `.not()` does not return a boolean, it returns a jQuery object. Read the documentation.

Answer (score 1):

The filter isn't necessary, just call `.not()` on the matched wrap elements. `.not()` filters a set of matched elements, it doesn't return a boolean. By calling `.not()` on your `$(this)`, you're still returning a jQuery object, which evaluates to `true`.

```js
$('document').ready(function(){

  $('.wrap').not(':has(img, video)').css( "background-color", "red" );
    
});
```

```css
.wrap{
    border: 1px solid;
    display: block;
    margin: 10px 0 10px 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrap">
    <div class="content">
        abc
    </div>
</div>


<div class="wrap">
    <div class="content">
        <img>
            
        </img>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="wrap">
    <div class="content">
        <video></video>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

[.not()](http://api.jquery.com/val/) will return a jQuery object which will always be truthy.

The .filter() method has to return `true/false` based on whether to select the current element or not, since `not` returns a jQuery object it will be considered as truthy so all the elements which are passed to the `.filter()` will be selected. Instead you can use `.is()` which will return a boolean value.

Note: Don't know why you are not using `plainText`

```js
$('document').ready(function() {


  var plainText = $('.wrap').not(':has(img, video)');
  plainText.css('border', '1px solid blue')

  $('.wrap').filter(function(index) {
    return !$(this).is(':has(img, video)');
  }).css("background-color", "red");

});
```

```css
.wrap {
  border: 1px solid;
  display: block;
  margin: 10px 0 10px 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrap">
  <div class="content">
    abc
  </div>
</div>


<div class="wrap">
  <div class="content">
    <img />
  </div>
</div>

<div class="wrap">
  <div class="content">
    <video></video>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

use `is()` in jquery it will return true or false, if you use `not` it always return `object` not a Boolean

```
 $('.wrap').filter(function (index) {
     return !$(this).is(':has(img,video)');
 }).css("background-color", "red");
```

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/gs7zkvnm/)

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.wrap').filter(function( index ) {
   return $(this).not(':has(img,video)').length;
}).css( "background-color", "red" );
```